# Is the following map onto or Bijective?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is this map onto or bijective?

From $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

$\left( x,y,z,t\right) \rightarrow (x-t,z-y,x-2y+2z-t)$

I understand that for it to be onto, it has to have the property that for every element of x in X there is a corresponding y in Y such that $f\left( x\right)=y$

But how would I show that this is surjective and or bijective ?

Comment: In http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784239/find-the-rank-and-nullity-of-the-following-matrix it was explained how to find the matrix representation of this transformation. You said you knew how to find the rank. Find the rank, if it is equal to 3, then the map is onto. Otherwise it is not.

Comment: Is there some sot of theorem ? Or general rule of thumb then ?

Comment: Since your mapping to a lower dimension it cannot be bijective since no injective map exits that maps from a higher to lower dimensional vector space.

Comment: Surjective is the same as onto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with finite dimensional vector spaces and linear maps, you should always think to the “rank-nullity” theorem.

> *If $f\colon V\to W$ is a linear map between finite dimensional vector spaces, then $\dim\operatorname{Im}(f)+\dim\ker(f)=\dim V$.*

Since $f$ is surjective if and only if $\operatorname{Im}(f)=W$ and it is injective if and only if $\ker(f)=\{0\}$, we have the following consequences.

1. If $\dim V<\dim W$, then $f$ is not surjective
2. If $\dim V>\dim W$, then $f$ is not injective
3. If $\dim V=\dim W$, then $f$ is injective if and only if it is surjective.

Note that in case 1 $f$ need not be injective, in case 2 $f$ need not be surjective and in case 3 $f$ can be neither injective nor surjective.

*Proof of 1*. By the rank-nullity theorem,
$$
\dim W>\dim V=
\dim\operatorname{Im}(f)+\dim\ker(f)\ge
\dim\operatorname{Im}(f)
$$
so $\operatorname{Im}(f)\ne W$. QED

Do similarly for the other two statements.

In your situation, $f$ may be surjective, but is certainly not injective. The matrix of the linear map is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -2 & 2 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which has rank $2$, so the image has dimension $2$ and the map is not surjective.

Without matrices, you can see that
$$
f(x,y,z,t)=(x-t)(1,0,1)+(z-y)(0,1,2)
$$
so the image is generated by $(1,0,1)$ and $(0,1,2)$ and therefore its dimension is at most $2$ (it is actually $2$, because the two vectors are linearly independent).

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- "for every element of x in X there is a corresponding y in Y such that $f(x)=y$" is part of the definition of a function. This is true for all functions.
- "Onto" or "surjective" mean the same thing.
- "Surjective" means that for every element $y \in Y$, there is a corresponding $x \in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. It's important that you choose $y$ first and then find the corresponding $x$. In the context of linear transformations, you need to find the rank of the transformation and it is surjective if and only if the rank is equal to the dimensionality of the range.
- A function is "injective" or "one-to-one" if $f(x_1)=f(x_2) \implies x_1=x_2$. In the context of linear transformations, this means that a linear transformation is injective if and only if the nullity is 0.
- A function is bijective if it is both injective and surjective. However, in the context of linear transformations, this can only happen if the domain and range have equal dimensionalities which in this case, they clearly do not.

Answer (score 1):

A linear mapping is bijective if and only if there is a one-to-one correspondence between the domain and co-domain. Clearly this is impossible (intuitively and mathematically, by $dim(KerT) + dim(ImT) = dimV$) between $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$.

If you want to find if it is surjective, the imagespace of $T$ must be equal to $\mathbb{R}^3$ (i.e. you need such that there are 3 linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to span $imT$).

Express the linear transformation in a matrix $A$ (the easiest basis are of course, the standard bases), the row-reduce to find the $rankA$, what does the result of this tell you of $dim(ImT)$ and what result do you require such that the map is surjective?)